# varnish remove some cookie command explanation

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Please explain the working of

```
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|; ) *__utm.=[^;]+;? *", "\1");
```

It should match the utm part of the cookie header and remove such cookies.
what does \1 represent? and how does it iterate over all utm cookies.

At once it seems it removes all cookies before __utm cookie.

Answer (score 0):

This regex removes all Google Analytics campaign cookies from the headers and will keep all other cookies (before or after the __utm cookies). The `\1` represents everything matching on `(^|; )`.